# Solving error for iterative program

Tags: java, iteration

i was trying to create an iterative program with user input, copied from this textbook of mine but on the returns i keep getting an error of: " Multiple markers at this line - The primitive type int of a does not have a field b - 
Syntax error on token ",", . expected"

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Code3 {



public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  
    System.out.println("Enter A: ");
    int a = scanner.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Enter B: ");
    int b = scanner.nextInt(); 


    if (a==b)
        return;

    if (a>b)
        return (a-b, b);
    else 
        return (a, b-a);
}
}
```

Comment: `main` doesn't return anything, and you can't return a tuple like you did. What are you expecting to happen with the results.

Comment: i want it to be displayed out to the user

Comment: In that case I suggest you use `System.out.println` as you have done already.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  
    System.out.println("Enter A: ");
    int a = scanner.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Enter B: ");
    int b = scanner.nextInt(); 

    if (a>b) {
        System.out.println("Results: " + (a-b) + ", " + b);
    } else if(a < b) {
        System.out.println("Results: " + a + ", " + (b-a));
    }
}
```